# Subsetting data with a column condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which contains `Date`, `Visitor_ID` and `Pages` columns. In the `Page_visited` column there are different row wise entries for each dates. Please refer the below table to understand the data.

```
[| Dates      | Visitor_ID| Pages    |
|:------     |:---------:| -----:   |
| 10/1/2021  | 1         | xy       |
| 10/1/2021  | 1         | step2    |
|10/1/2021   | 1         | xx       |
|10/1/2021   | 1         | NetBanking|
| 10/1/2021  | 2         | step1     |
| 10/1/2021  | 2         | xy        |
|10/1/2021   | 3         | step1     |
|10/1/2021   | 3         | NetBanking|
|11/1/2021   | 4         | step1     |
|12/1/2021   | 4         | NetBanking|][1]
```

Desired output:

```
 Date          Visitor_ID
|10/1/2021   | 1         | 
|10/1/2021   | 3         |
```

the output should be a subset of actual data where the condition is that if for same Visitor_ID the page contains string "step" before string "Netbanking in same date then return the Visitor ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To initialise your dataframe you could do:

```
import pandas as pd
columns = ["Dates", "Visitor_ID", "Pages"]
records = [
    ["10/1/2021", 1, "xy"],
    ["10/1/2021", 1, "step2"],
    ["10/1/2021", 1, "NetBanking"],
    ["10/1/2021", 2, "step1"],
    ["10/1/2021", 2, "xy"],
    ["10/1/2021", 3, "step1"],
    ["10/1/2021", 3, "NetBanking"],
    ["11/1/2021", 4, "step1"],
    ["12/1/2021", 4, "NetBanking"]]
data = pd.DataFrame().from_records(records, columns=columns)
data["Dates"] = pd.DatetimeIndex(data["Dates"])
index_names = columns[:2]
data.set_index(index_names, drop=True, inplace=True)
```

Note that I have left out your third line in the records, otherwise I cannot reproduce your desired output. I have made this a multi-index data frame in order to easily loop over the groups 'date/visitor'. The structure of the dataframe looks like:

```
print(data)

                            Pages
Dates      Visitor_ID            
2021-10-01 1                   xy
           1                step2
           1           NetBanking
           2                step1
           2                   xy
           3                step1
           3           NetBanking 
2021-11-01 4                step1
2021-12-01 4           NetBanking
```

Now to select the customers from the same date and from the same group, I am going to loop over these groups and use 2 masks to select the required records:

```
for date_time, data_per_date in data.groupby(level=0):
    for visitor, data_per_visitor in data_per_date.groupby(level=0):
        # select the column with the Pages
        pages = data_per_visitor["Pages"].str
        
        # make 2 boolean masks, for the records with step and netbanking
        has_step = pages.contains("step")
        has_netbanking = pages.contains("NetBanking")

        # to get the records after each 'step' records, apply a diff on 'has_step' 
        # Convert to int first for the correct result
        # each diff with outcome -1 fulfills this requirement. Make a 
        # mask based on this requirement
        diff_step = has_step.astype(int).diff()
        records_after_step = diff_step == -1

        # combine the 2 mask to create your final mask to make a selection
        mask = records_after_step & has_netbanking

        # select the records and print to screen
        selection = data_per_visitor[mask]
        if not selection.empty:
            print(selection.reset_index()[index_names])
```

This gives the following output:

```
       Dates  Visitor_ID
0 2021-10-01           1
1 2021-10-01           3
```

EDIT:
I was reading your question again. The solution above assumed that only records with 'NetBanking' *directly* following a record with 'step' is valid. That is why  I thought your example input was not corresponding with your desired output. However, in case you are allowing rows in between an occurrence with 'step' and the first 'netbanking', the solution does not work. In that case, it is better to explicitly iterate of the rows of your dataframe per date and client id. An example then would be:

```
for date_time, data_per_date in data.groupby(level=0):
    for visitor, data_per_visitor in data_per_date.groupby(level=0):
        after_step = False
        index_selection = list()
        data_per_visitor.reset_index(inplace=True)
        for index, records in data_per_visitor.iterrows():
            page = records["Pages"]
            if "step"  in page and not after_step:
                after_step = True
            if "NetBanking" in page and after_step:
                index_selection.append(index)
                after_step = False

        selection = data_per_visitor.reindex(index_selection)
        if not selection.empty:
            print(selection.reset_index()[index_names]
```

Normally I would not recommend to use 'iterrows' as it is really slow, but in this case I don't see an easy other solution. The output of the second algorithm is the same as the first for my data. In case you do include the third line from your example data, the second algorithm still gives the same output.